# Book involving a witch who placed bread in front of a stone circle

Tags: story-identification, magic, childrens-novel

I know this isn't a lot to go on, but I'm wondering if anyone remembers a book or story with a witch placing bread in a stone circle / henge to hide their numbers. I think there was a chase through modern-ish streets, so I think it would have been from the '90s or early '00s maybe. It would have been a kids' book around 8-12 maybe; UK primary school age.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually read this? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Would have been around 2003 i think Can't recall the cover sadly, realise it's not much to go on

Comment: What do you mean by "hide their numbers"?  Making a group of witches appear like only one person?

Comment: Or maybe to make it look like there were more stones in the circle than there actually were?